# Docker container ID on a Windows Container

Tags: docker

I need to get the docker container Id inside the running windows container. When container OS is a Linux, there is a file (*/proc/self/cgroup*) which stores container Id. Is there a registry key or anything else to get the container Id inside a running windows OS container?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to your question? If so, can you post the answer for the rest of us?

Comment: @MarkR, admittedly a hack, but can you not set an env var to the container ID in an environment variable?

Comment: @MarkR what is the use case for this? (curiously asking)

Comment: I am implementing a software license scheme and the container ID is very helpful to use as part of a fingerprint to uniquely identify a running instance of the software. So I need to get something that cannot easily be circumvented by the user. In Linux it is easy but I don't know how to get this information in Windows.

Comment: From a bit of searching on Github, I've found that it's a long time requested feature (like 2014) but probably not enough. See these issues [#1105](https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/issues/1105) [#8427](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8427) [#26331](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/26331) maybe worth following

Answer (score 0):

Container ID is your hostname inside the Docker.

To get the hostname/container id you can use `hostname` command

Comment: Correct, but hostname can be set during run "docker run --hostname=value OR docker run -h value" I need the 64 characters long container ID.

Answer (score 0):

if you run

```
docker ps -a
```

it will return a list of containers in you docker.

Comment: I want to get the id inside the container, not on the host computer.